# when using dependency injection, should I always pass an interface

Tags: object-oriented, interfaces, dependency-injection, methods

When using depending injection, you generally pass everything around as an interface (perhaps with the exception of primitives and strings). That allows you to easily chance the behavior, without changing the implementation.

Is there ever a case where I should not be passing some complex object through an interface though?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This depends on the programming language, the availability of a mocking framework and your need for mocking those complex objects. For C# and Java, there are frameworks available which allow you to mock out classes without creating interfaces first. (In the environment where I work, we don't use any of those frameworks, so whenever we have to mock a class for a unit test, we are going to create an interface.) In C++, you can avoid the need for interface-based mocking by injecting your "complex class" as a template parameter into every other component which is going to use it (the drawback is you have to templatize those classes, which means a certain amount of overhead).

In weakly typed languages there's often not even a language construct "interface" because you can replace an object of a class just by an object of a different type as long as the replacement fulfills the implicit contract (i.e. provides methods with correct names and signature).

Furthermore, I agree that DI does not work well with infrastructure classes like "strings". See this [former PSE question & my answer to it](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/159554/dependency-injection-good-practices-to-reduce-boilerplate-code).

I would like to add that your question sounds like "shall I always provide an interface 'just in case'". IMHO it is better to follow the YAGNI principle, start without an interface, and as soon as you need one, maybe for mocking purposes, refactor your code and introduce the interface afterwards.

Answer (score 5):

Any case where there is only ever going to be a single implementation.

Any case where you are passing an instance of a derived type, rather than an instance that fulfills a particular interface.

Comment: When can you know there is only going to be a single implementation? Maybe there is only one right now, but I'm pretty stupid, and I always assume that someone will come later and think of a better version.

Comment: @dgrin91 - things like strings. Nobody is going to make a "new" string. Likewise if you're implementing something that represents a Date or an Atom, things where people aren't just going to make up or redefine some concept. The concept is fixed by reality.

Comment: @Telastyn Why? What if I think of a better (ie more optimized) string implementation? For example, in Java `String`s implement `CharSequence`. So if I think of some new optimization of `String`, I can easily swap it in if the program uses DI with `CharSequences`.

Comment: When you've actually got a second implementation, refactor so that you're using an interface.

Comment: @Dgrin91 - What are the odds of that? Program design is a series of trade-offs. What is the odds that you'll need to swap out your string implementation, versus the cost of writing all of the boilerplate code that allows you to do that easily (and the maintenance cost of people misunderstanding or misusing the `CharSequence`)? And if you wrote the original class, what are the odds that you need a _different_ implementation as opposed to refactoring the existing class to use the better implementation?

Comment: The odds might be low, but the overhead seems low as well. Its not hard to write `CharSequence` instead of `String`. Meanwhile, you still have the option to refactor your original class. But either way, strings are more of an exception (which I mentioned in my question). I've never heard of any other class that can only ever have one implementation.

Comment: Most classes only have one implementation, unless you're counting stubs and mocks as an "implementation."  My current project has about three hundred classes; about a dozen conform to an interface with multiple implementations.

Comment: @DavidGrinberg: I am sure you underestimate the drawbacks of such an approach. See my answer here: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/159554/dependency-injection-good-practices-to-reduce-boilerplate-code/159566#159566

Comment: +1, it is rare that you'll need more than 1 instance of a class at a given time.  Better ways of doing things are usually replacements instead of coexisting with the previous way.  Plus, requiring an interface and a class at the same time can lead to poor naming if the default class is not substantially different than the interface.

Comment: @DavidGrinberg You will drive yourself absolutely batty if you have an interface for every single class in the system. That's a lot of redundancy and boilerplate. Also, *there are things that an interface can't do* that a class can. You can't implement binary methods efficiently in an interface (e.g. merging two sets efficiently requires access to the private details of both sets. A function that takes two `ISet`s knows nothing about either one.)

Comment: @DavidGrinberg, you should always first assume there will only be one implementation of a class, because it will end up being true way more often than when it turns out to be false.

Comment: @RobertHarvey old answer but I disagree with you on this one - having interfaces for injected dependencies gives you extension points for decorators, adapters etc. and naturally leads to a more decomposed and adaptable codebase when those things are utilised. The overhead of having interfaces that you might not "use" is outweighed by the converse of breaking changes in consumers when you introduce one, or of the poor composition that often follows when behavioural changes are subsequently made by changing components (and tests) rather than plugging in/removing them.

Comment: @AntP: Make sure you tell Doc Brown that as well (he wrote the accepted answer on this question).